# Where are the best places to post chiddushim?

Tags: publications

Over a couple of years I've BH put together a booklet of chiddushim in English on various topics (Lifnei Iver, Bal Tosif, Maris Ayin, Chatzi Shiur, Kavona Lotzeis, Yehoreg V'Al Yaavor, P'sik Reisha by Issurei Hano'oh, Bedikas Chometz, Bor Birshus Horabim) following a lomdish Brisker/Telzer style with all the necessary background in each piece to be able to understand the question and then the chiddush which I thought of. It also has a glossary for Hebrew terms. I think they'd hopefully be really enjoyable for experienced learners but also a tool for less experienced learners or younger bochurim (and girls) to find excitement, enjoyment and conceptual depth in gemara.

Does anyone know which places and sites would be best to send these to to be able to reach the most people who may take a look and benefit? I've emailed many yeshivos around the world but have heard little back. I'd love to reach these people and for them to enjoy the chiddushim and to hear back from them on their thoughts.

Comment: Very beautiful, I hope you will continue to write and publish chidusim. Yshar Loach!

Comment: Aw that's so sweet Dr. Shmuel, thank you so much! Thank you so much Kouty as well. I hope you'll both enjoy them if you end up reading! Would love to hear what you think of any of them by email or whatsapp (details are on the bottom of the booklet pdf's front page. I haven't reached out to publishers, do you think that would help? It's not my goal to have it become an 'official' sefer, I just want to get it out to many people all over who could benefit from it (and my nefesh habehamis would love to hear back from them too haha).

Comment: The people you'll be targeting aren't going to have "online" lol

Comment: So making it a sefer will be the best way possible especially if it'll be in English - that'll reach a lot of people

Comment: Ok - thank you guys SO much. Dr Shmuel; good idea; it's so helpful. publishers would know about this. TwoOs, thanks a lot for the point about the sefer, I'm thinking now maybe that really is the best way to reach people. If that ends up happening maybe I'll make the sefer for free though and then it could be of use to more people. I plan to ask a publisher about all this and see what they think. Re: online, I think it could be of use for a large range of orthodox Jews (and iyH all types of Jews), of which I think many will have online - like us - but I agree that some won't.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/759

Comment: what do you mean with that Double AA? I didn't know the answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

I would self-publish with Amazon and see what feedback you get. Once you have improved the quality of your sefer you can then approach a traditional publisher, like Feldheim. The advantage of this approach is that with Amazon it is trivial to make updates and changes, but once you submit to a traditional publisher, the text is locked in.

There is no cost to self-publish with Amazon, and ordering author copies is amazingly cheap.

Comment: "once you submit to a traditional publisher, the text is locked in": I've never published a book, myself, so take this with a grain of salt, but I understand this not to be the case. After a book's submitted to a publisher it can be revised heavily by the author.

Comment: I used Lulu to make my collections. Effectively, you do all the work (proofing, formatting etc) yourself and the system converts what you upload to a pdf and the system prints and binds your copies when you or someone else orders it. Then you print up copies and give them to your friends. Or you can pay for marketing packages. If you make a couple of copies and give to rabbeim whom you respect and get haskamos then another publisher might take notice.

Comment: Thank you the GRAPKE that is really helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/new) allows you to make a page of sources plus your own comments, which might work for you.